# How to sort months containing zero value in SSRS chart

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012

I'm creating a SSRS chart that show total results for each months within the current and previous year. My query is showing values and also showing 0 values for applicable month and year. My question is when I create a chart, months are sorted except for those with 0 values.
For example, My months is sorted by financial year, year and month. October is right at the beginning of the chart as the previous financial year had 0 value and the rest of the months are all in the correct sort order. Is there a way I can fix this in SSRS and move October to its correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this
Chart data- category Groups Properties - sorting section

Sorting is done here.